# How to trigger a function when page is changed in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am facing a question/issue.

I want to know on how to trigger a function when a page is changed in VUEJS.

Can someone help in some code snippets to make more understandable?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, Have a look at navigation guards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Comment: @YashMaheshwari, I tried ```beforeRouteEnter```, thanks for the help. But is it possible to add globally the beforeRouteEnter? if so, then which page needs to be added as I have many pages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to trigger the function from one page and let it execute on another one?
Otherwise you could use lifecycle hooks as mounted() or created() when page loads. It will trigger a function as soon as page is loaded.

Comment: yes, i want to trigger the function from one page and let it execute on another one